# Ajuda com duplicar conteúdo

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Estou duplicando uma div com um conteúdo que é preenchido via um formulário na mesma página, porém quando se duplica ele as funções em jQuery não funcionam nesta nova div que foi duplicada, as funções continuam funcionando nas outras divs que já vinham na tela.

Vou postar meu código e minha tela:

jQuery:

```
$('.btn-novo-endereco').on('click', function(event){
        var tipoEndereco = $('.tipoEndereco').val();
        var destinatario = $('.destinatario').val();
        var endereco = $('#enderecoEmpresa').val();
        var numero = $('#numeroEmpresa').val();
        var complemento = $('#complementoEmpresa').val();
        var referencia = $('#referenciaEmpresa').val();
        var cep = $('#cepEmpresa').val();
        var bairro = $('#bairroEmpresa').val();
        var cidade = $('#cidadeEmpresa').val();
        var estado = $('#estadoEmpresa').val();

        //gera um novo id para os novos endereços
        var novoId = "endereco" + idAutomatico;
        idAutomatico++;

        var htmlNovoEndereco = 
                '<div class="col-md-6">' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                '<div class="container endereco-cadastrado">' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' + tipoEndereco + '<span class="icon-edit"><a href="#" alt="Editar" title="Editar" class="editar-endereco" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colapseEditarEndereco" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="colapseEditarEndereco"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a></span>' +
                '<span class="icon-delete"><a href="#" alt="Deletar" class="deletar-endereco" title="Deletar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' + destinatario +'</div>'+
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                 endereco + ',' + numero + ' - ' + complemento + 
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                cep + ' - ' + bairro + 
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                cidade + '/' + estado + 
                '</div>' + 
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12 font-size-14px checka bg-light endereco-nao-padrao ">' +
                '<div class="form-check form-check-inline">' +
                '<input class="form-check-input check-padrao" type="radio" name="definirPadrao" id="'+ novoId +'" value="padrao'+idAutomatico+'">' +
                '<label class="form-check-label" for="'+novoId+'">Definir como endereço padrão</label>' +
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';


        $(htmlNovoEndereco).clone().prependTo('.novos-enderecos');

        $('.camposNovoEndereco').fadeOut('fast');

        limpa_formulario_cep();
        $('.tipoEndereco').val("");
        $('.destinatario').val("");
        $('#cepEmpresa').val("");
    })
```

Minha Tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Quais são os eventos que não funcionam (o código)? Por exemplo, o da "lixeira"?

Comment: Boa tarde @Sam sim os da lixeira e o input radio, que deveriam funcionar e não funcionam!

 $('.deletar-endereco').on('click', function(event){
            // pergunta antes de apagar
            var apagar = confirm('Deseja realmente apagar o endereço?');
            // verifica se o apagar foi clicado em ok, retorna  ( true ou false ), se sim executa a primeira condição
            if(apagar){
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();

            }
        })

Comment: Troque para `$(document).on('click', '.deletar-endereco', function(event){`

Comment: Sempre use essa sintaxe quando for mexer com elementos dinâmicos.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar e retorno com a solução! =)

Comment: Show @Sam era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado! @Sam =)